# getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why am i getting a `NullPointerException`?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Tetris
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                TFrame w1=new TFrame();
                w1.setVisible(true);
                w1.setDefaultCloseOperation(w1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
            }
        });
    }
}
class TFrame extends JFrame
{
    TFrame()
    {   
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(400,800);
        JTPanel jp1=new JTPanel();
        jp1.setBackground(Color.red);
        jp1.setLayout(null);
        jp1.setBounds(0,0,400,800);
        add(jp1);
    }

}
class JTPanel extends JPanel
{
    Shape[] s;
    Rectangle2D r; 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D gd=(Graphics2D)g;

        r=(Rectangle2D)s[0];
        System.out.println("first");        
        r.setFrame(80,20,100,200);
        gd.draw(s[0]);

    }
    JTPanel()
    {   
        //setBackground(Color.red);
        Shape[] s=new Shape[3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            s[i]=new Rectangle2D.Double();
            System.out.println("second");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Because you're tying to pass or access or invoke a method on something which is `null`. Check the line number in 1st line of stacktrace and trackback it in the code.

Comment: Give us the stack trace.

Comment: If you show the stacktrace it would be a lot easier for someone to help

Answer (score 1):

Because you never initialize the `s` field of the `JTPanel` class. Try changing this line:

```
    Shape[] s=new Shape[3];
```

to

```
    this.s=new Shape[3];
```

With this change you'll be initializing the field, rather than just creating a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've declared `Shape[] s;` but not initialized it and yet using it in the line `r=(Rectangle2D)s[0];`.

Answer (score 1):

s in JTPanel is always null. When you create an array in the constructor you assign it to a local variable called s rather than the instance variable. This will fix your problem:

```
JTPanel()
{   
    //setBackground(Color.red);
    s=new Shape[3];
```